# Filter tests after discover

Tags: python, python-unittest

I'm currently running my tests like this:

```
tests = unittest.TestLoader().discover('tests')
unittest.TextTestRunner().run(tests)
```

Now I want to run a specific test knowing his name (like `test_valid_user`) but not knowing his class. If there is more than one test with such name than I would like to run all such tests. Is there any way to filter tests after `discover`?

Or maybe there are other solutions to this problem (please note that it shouldn't be done from command line)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the `unittest.loader.TestLoader.testMethodPrefix` instance variable to change the test methods filter according to a different prefix than "test".

Say you have a `tests` directory with this king of unit tests:

```
import unittest


class MyTest(unittest.TestCase):
    def test_suite_1(self):
        self.assertFalse("test_suite_1")

    def test_suite_2(self):
        self.assertFalse("test_suite_2")

    def test_other(self):
        self.assertFalse("test_other")
```

You can write your own `discover` function to discover only test functions starting with "test_suite_", for instance:

```
import unittest


def run_suite():
    loader = unittest.TestLoader()
    loader.testMethodPrefix = "test_suite_"
    suite = loader.discover("tests")
    result = unittest.TestResult()
    suite.run(result)
    for test, info in result.failures:
        print(info)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    run_suite()
```

*remark*: the argument "tests" in the `discover` method is a directory path, so you may need to write a fullpath.

As a result, you'll get:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/tests/test_my_module.py", line 8, in test_suite_1
    self.assertFalse("test_suite_1")
AssertionError: 'test_suite_1' is not false

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/path/to/tests/test_my_module.py", line 11, in test_suite_2
    self.assertFalse("test_suite_2")
AssertionError: 'test_suite_2' is not false
```

Answer (score 1):

Another simpler way, would be to use [py.test](http://pytest.org/latest/getting-started.html) with the `-k` option which does a test name keyword scan. It will run any tests whose name matches the keyword expression.

Although that is using the command-line which you didn't want, please not that you can call the command-line from your code using `subprocess.call` to pass any arguments you want dynamically.

E.g.: Assuming you have the following tests:

```
def test_user_gets_saved(self): pass
def test_user_gets_deleted(self): pass
def test_user_can_cancel(self): pass
```

You can call `py.test` from cli:

```
$ py.test -k "test_user"
```

Or from code:

```
return_code = subprocess.call('py.test -k "test_user"', shell=True)
```

Answer (score 0):

There are two ways to run a single test method:

**Command line:**

```
$ python -m unittest test_module.TestClass.test_method
```

**Using Python script:**

```
import unittest

class TestMyCode(unittest.TestCase):

    def setUp(self):
        pass

    def test_1(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

    def test_2(self):
        self.assertTrue(True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    testSuite = unittest.TestSuite()
    testSuite.addTest(TestMyCode('test_1'))
    runner=unittest.TextTestRunner()
    runner.run(testSuite)
```

> Output:
>
> ------------------------------------------------------------
>
> Ran 1 test in 0.000s
>
> OK